# Reducing multi-variable functions to a composition of 1- or 2-variable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, special-functions

There are some special functions of 3 or more complex variables that are analytic in some domain (a region in $\mathbb C^n$) with respect to each variable. To give some examples: the [incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B(z; a, b)$, the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) $\Phi(z, s, a)$, the [Weierstrass elliptic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html) $\wp(z;g_2,g_3)$, hypergeometric-family functions, etc.

Is it possible to express each (or at least some) of these functions as a composition of several analytic functions of 1 or 2 complex variables?

Or, if we restrict their domain to reals, it is possible to express them as a composition of several inifinitely differentiable (with respect to each variable) functions of 1 or 2 real variables?

The same question applies to functions of 2 variables (e.g. polylogarithms, incomplete elliptic integrals, Hurwitz zeta function, Bessel-family functions, etc.): Is it possible to represent them as a composition of several infinitely differentiable functions of 1 variable and the single fixed function of 2 variables $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$?

---

To give an example when the answer to the last question is positive, consider the [complete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $B(a,b)$. It can be represented as
$$B(a,b)=\exp\big((\ln\Gamma(a)+\ln\Gamma(b))+(-\ln\Gamma(a+b))\big)$$
that is a composition of the 2-variable sum function and several infinitely differentiable 1-variable functions $x\mapsto\exp(x)$, $x\mapsto\ln\Gamma(x)$ and $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Kolmogorov's superposition theorem? It's very close to what you're asking if I interpret your question correctly. The only difference is it requires a sum over $2n+1$ and $n$ terms if your function's domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Page 2: http://cca-net.de/vasco/publications/kolmogorov.pdf

Comment: As far as I know, the solution given in Kolmogorov's superposition theorem doesn't use analytic functions, see the middle of page 2.

Comment: Re-posted at [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/231771/9550).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for [essentially the same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140859/kolmogorov-superposition-for-smooth-functions) asked earlier at *MathOverflow*.

**TL;DR**

There exist analytic functions $f$ of 3 variables such that they cannot be represented as a composition of continuously differentiable functions of two variables. The general problem in the class $C^\infty$ seems to be still open.